# Python re.findall matches last the last match instead of the first

Tags: python, regex

I have a csv file with lots of twitter data from which I want to extract nodes and edges to create a network file for Social Network Analysis.

The data I want are located in row[11] and row[12]. I add them together, inserting four & just to make an easy delimiter.

```
for row in reader:
    interactions = row[11] + "&&&&" + row[12]
    print interactions #for debugging only
    edgeST = re.findall(r'^(.*)&&&&.*@([A-Za-z0-9([A-Za-z0-9_]+)', interactions, flags = re.MULTILINE)
    print edgeST
```

The output from both prints look like this (first line prints the entire interactions string, the second line the result of the re.findall):

```
GaryStokesKSPS&&&&RT @PBS: .@SciGirls Season 3 is now on @YouTube! Watch now: http://t.co/YHH23ADDq9 #SciGirls #STEM #CitizenScience
[('GaryStokesKSPS', 'YouTube')]
```

In this case, my first parenthesis matches the source node username ('GaryStokesKSPS'), which is fine. But then I get a match for 'Youtube', but not for @PBS or @SciGirls. The last match is returned, but not the previous ones. This pattern occurs throughout my entire dataset.

How can I get A) All matches and/or B) Only the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a non-greedy match: change

```regex
^(.*)&&&&.*@([A-Za-z0-9([A-Za-z0-9_]+)
```

into

```regex
^(.*)&&&&.*?@([A-Za-z0-9([A-Za-z0-9_]+)
```

The former matches as much text as possible, so your text is getting split up as

```
GaryStokesKSPS&&&&RT @PBS: .@SciGirls Season 3 is now on @YouTube! Watch now: ...
\________________/\_____________________________________/@\_____/
     (.*)&&&&                 greedy match .*              group
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you Mauris. This makes the expression match the first occurence! Will accept as answer in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I’m not sure about this part:

```
([A-Za-z0-9([A-Za-z0-9_]+)
```

There is a character class (`[]`) with the following characters and ranges: `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `(`, `[`, `A-Z` again, `a-z` again, `0-9` again, and `_`.

You probably made a mistake there as it’s the same as `([A-Za-z0-9([_]+)`. And the brackets aren’t actually allowed in Twitter names. You probably meant to match for something like this: `([A-Za-z0-9_]+)`.

That being said, to fix your problem, you need a *non-greedy* match before the `@` character. Change it to this:

```
^(.*?)&&&&.*?@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)
    ↑       ↑
the question marks make this non-greedy
```

Comment: Yes. First of all, you are right about my expression. I wasn't completely aware of what I was doing there for a second. I shortened it to your line, and it works. And looks nicer :). Secondly, yes, the non-greediness makes the expression return the first match instead of the last. Thank you for solution and for the explanation!